# Django : Making exc_info optional in logging formatter

Tags: python, django

I'm using the following formatter in Django for logging warnings & errors in django.request module:

```
'format': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s\n %(exc_info)s'
```

This prints `None` when no exception has occurred. Is it possible to skip `exc_info` when there's no exception in the formatter?

Here's the logging call:

```
logger.error('', exc_info=True)
```

Comment: @That1Guy `if/else` in logging configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly include `%(exc_info)s` inside your logging format configuration: when logging exceptions, the traceback and related stuff will be automatically added.

Quoting the documentation of the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html):

> There are two keyword arguments in kwargs which are inspected: exc_info which, if it does not evaluate as false, **causes exception information to be added to the logging message**. If an exception tuple (in the format returned by sys.exc_info()) is provided, it is used; otherwise, sys.exc_info() is called to get the exception information.

<sub>*(Emphasis mine.)*</sub>

Also, pay attention to the [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) section:

> `exc_info`      |      You shouldn’t need to format this yourself.

Comment: `exc_info` is automatically passed only when using `logger.exception()`. If I use `logger.warning` or `logger.error`, I've to explicitly set `exc_info=True`.

Comment: @user4150760: do not confuse the `exc_info` **argument** you pass to the Logger functions, with the `exc_info` **attribute** of LogRecord objects that is automatically formatted into log records. ;) It's true that you have to pass the argument explicitly, but you don't need to format the attribute.